# How to add a semi-colon ; after each create ddl statement using shell scripts

Tags: shell, unix, hadoop, hive

I am trying to add a semi-colon (;) after each create view Hive ddl statement. I have a file that has the below ddl statements in them:

```
CREATE VIEW `db1.table1` AS SELECT * FROM db2.table1
CREATE VIEW `db1.table2` AS SELECT * FROM db2.table2
CREATE VIEW `db1.table3` AS SELECT * FROM db3.table3
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `db1.table4`(
  `cus_id` int,
  `ren_mt` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'skip.header.line.count'='1', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1558705259')
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `sndbx_cmcx.effective_month1`(
  `customeridentifier` bigint, 
  `renewalmonth` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='false', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1558713596')
```

I want it to look like below. After each create view statement there is a ; and after each create table there's a ;..

```
CREATE VIEW `db1.table1` AS SELECT * FROM db2.table1;
CREATE VIEW `db1.table2` AS SELECT * FROM db2.table2;
CREATE VIEW `db1.table3` AS SELECT * FROM db3.table3;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `db1.table4`(
  `cus_id` int,
  `ren_mt` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'skip.header.line.count'='1', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1558705259');
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `sndbx_cmcx.effective_month1`(
  `customeridentifier` bigint, 
  `renewalmonth` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='false', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1558713596');
```

Here is my shell script that I use:

```
#Change database before you run the script
 hiveDBName=$1;


 showcreate="show create table "
 terminate=";"
 tables=`hive -e "use $hiveDBName;show tables;"`
 tab_list=`echo "${tables}"`

  for list in $tab_list
  do
         echo "Generating table script for " #${hiveDBName}.${list}
          showcreatetable=${showcreatetable}${showcreate}${hiveDBName}.${list}${terminate}
        done

        echo " ====== Create Tables ======= : "# $showcreatetable

 #Creates a filter ddls
 hive -e "use $hiveDBName; ${showcreatetable}"> a.sql
 #Removes the Warn: from the file
 grep -v "WARN" a.sql > /home/path/my_ddls/${hiveDBName}_extract_all_tables.sql

 echo "Removing Filter File"
 #Remove Filter file
 rm -f a.sql

#Puts a ; after each create view statement in the document 
sed -i '/transient/s/$/;/' "/home/path/my_ddls/${hiveDBName}_extract_all_tables.sql"
```

This generates the ddls but it only puts a ; after the create table statement but it doesn't put it after each create view statement.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: I would do a cheat and separate each semi-colonable statement with a blank line. Then something like `awk 'BEGIN{RS=:\n\n";ORS=";\n\n"}{print} file > file.fix` or similar. Search here for `[awk] RS=` if this doesn't work. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd take the easy way and make use of the possibilities that the `;` doesn't have to be on the same line as the (end of the) statement and that there may be an empty statement. This gives:

```
sed -i -e '/^CREATE/i;' -e '$a;' "/home/path/my_ddls/${hiveDBName}_extract_all_tables.sql"
```